# How to implement a subquery to select rows that match two out of three topics?

Tags: mysql, subquery, logical-operators

How can  I find any books which cover exactly two of three different SQL systems without the set operator. I am using three  topic ids 'SSRV', 'ORA', 'MySQL' and need to output 2 out of any three. For example, the book could have a topic of SSRV and a topic of ORA, but not MySQL. Any two combination of these topics is sufficient to pass our filter.

I want to display the book_id and title of the book(s) that meet this test.

```
  SELECT book_id
       , title
    FROM a_bkinfo.books B
   WHERE book_id IN (
       SELECT book_id
         FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id = 'SSRV' )
  AND book_id IN (
       SELECT book_id
         FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id = 'ORA' )
  AND book_id IN (
       SELECT book_id
         FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id = 'MySQL' )
  AND book_id IN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM (  
                       SELECT book_id
                           ,  count(topic_id) AS topics
                         FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT 
                        GROUP BY book_id
                        HAVING count(topic_id) = 2
                        ) t 
              ;
```

UPDATED VERSION:

```
   SELECT book_id
 , title
 FROM a_bkinfo.books B
 WHERE book_id IN (
       SELECT book_id
         FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id ='SSRV'
        OR topic_id ='ORA' )
AND book_id IN (
        SELECT book_id
          FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id ='SSRV' 
        OR topic_id ='MySQL')
AND book_id IN (
        SELECT book_id
          FROM a_bkinfo.book_topics BT
    WHERE topic_id ='ORA' 
        OR topic_id ='MySQL');
```

Comment: the updated query will also return books that are of all 3 types at once

Comment: So you explicitly only want 2 to match, but fail if all 3 match?  If a book covered all 3 topics I was looking for, why would I want to exclude it.  You also mention no "set" operator... are you referring to something like [where topic_id in ( 'ORA', 'SSRV', 'MySQL' )] and if so, why would that be a bad thing in the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.title, COUNT(*) FROM books b
INNER JOIN book_topics bt ON (b.book_id = bt.book_id)
GROUP BY b.book_id, b.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

this will work if you have only one row per book-topic relation in the book_topics. These pairs need to be unique as well. In case your data dont meet the requirements the more complicated query is needed.
**UPDATE**
As the book_id is the only unique identifier than this is the new version:

```
SELECT b.book_id FROM books b
INNER JOIN book_topics bt ON (b.book_id = bt.book_id)
GROUP BY b.book_id
HAVING COUNT(topic_id) = 2
```

Requirements are the same as above.

Comment: Title belongs to bt book_topics. In that case would I just join the two tables using the correlation subquery and the input above? If so, how would that look?

Comment: @user2966637 Are titles of the same book_id always equal?

Comment: check out my updated version. does that makes sense? the output looks correct.

Comment: different titles for the same book id? Can you describe more detailed your data model in terms of properties unicity and table relations?